# Converting JSON array to QByteArray

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have an array:  [0xa,0x0b,0x0c]

This is stored in QJsonArray, I want to cover this to a QByteArray.  I've been searching around for a solution and have come across several methods, this is what I have tried but its not right:

```
    QJsonObject::iterator itrBinary = objJSON.find(clsFileThread::mscszBinary);
    if ( itrBinary != objJSON.end() ) {
      QJsonArray aryBinary(itrBinary->toArray());
    //At this point aryBinary contains:
    //10,11,12 which is correct
      QJsonDocument doc(aryBinary);        
      QByteArray aryBytes(doc.toBinaryData());
    //Now aryBytes contains:
    //'q','b','j' why, how?
      qDebug() << aryBinary << aryBytes;
    }
```

After the qDebug I get:

```
    QJsonArray([10,11,12]) "qbjs\x01\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\f\x00\x00\x00J\x01\x00\x00j\x01\x00\x00\x8A\x01\x00\x00"
```

What I want in QBytesArray is exactly what was put into the QJsonArray, 10, 11, 12.

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: @eyllanesc, as I said in my post, what I expect in the QByteArray is 3 bytes containing, 10, 11 and 12.

Comment: When you convert to binary using QJsonDocument what you are converting is the json format ("[", "{", ":" and the values), what you must do is iterate and add it one by one to the QByteArray like: `QByteArray ba; for(auto v: your_array){ba.append(v->toInt());}`

Comment: @eyllanesc, thank you, I accept what you are saying, I would have thought there was already something to do exactly this?

Comment: see the update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to "eyllanesc" for input, I would have thought there would be a built in function to do this, but here is the solution:

```
    QJsonArray aryBinary(itrBinary->toArray());
    QJsonArray::iterator itrArray = aryBinary.begin();
    QByteArray aryBytes;
    while( itrArray != aryBinary.end() ) {
        aryBytes.append(static_cast<char>(itrArray->toInt()));
        itrArray++;
    }
    qDebug() << aryBinary << aryBytes;
```